# How to change font size of jqxtree

Tags: html, css, jqxwidgets, jqxtree

I have tried to change font size of jqxtree, but nothing worked.

Below are the tries:

1. Appliced embbed style for jqxtree div

   ```
   <div id="jqxTree" style="font-size: 8px;"></div>
   ```
2. Appliced css style for jqxtree div

   ```
     <div id="jqxTree" class="treeClass"></div>
   ```

   .treeClass{
       font-size: 8px;
   }

I googled and found that font size can be changble by custom theme. But I am looking for is there any way just change the font size of jqxtree without using custom theme. I know that custom theme is good option but right now my requirement is very small. As just want to change the font size do I need to load such a big js file and assuming may face any other issues and understanding css code bit stuff.

Url for change font size via custom theme: http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/changing-font/#post-22806

Note: loading data via JSON. I looking to fix this issue by css if possible.

Please help me to fix this issue by simple way. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you sure your text is right after that div? There is no `<p>`?

Comment: can you post your code on jsfiddle?

Comment: Updated my question. Please have review.

Comment: instead of doing `.treeClass{ font-size: 8px; }` do `#treeClass{ font-size: 8px; }` maybe there is a rule that overwriting your rule

Comment: @Almis, # method is for id based. so as you suggested, i have tried below: <div id="jqxTree" ></div>  and #jqxTree{font-size: 8px; }. But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved.

```
#jqxTree li{
    font-size:8px;
}
```

Please refer the below fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/zp5qeqn5/

Thanks to all!!!